# Word for 'possessing large gravity well'?

Tags: single-word-requests

> Is there a word which means "possessing a large gravity well/exerting much gravity"?

My friend suggested "gravacious" which, though not a word, sounds fitting. And in the non-existence of a such a word already, I will most likely begin using it.

Comment: _gravific_ Not necessarily a large 'amount' though. http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gravific

Comment: Putting aside nitpicking over the difference between *weight* and *mass*, I'd just say ***heavy***. Of course, if you're *heavy with child*, you could be described as ***gravid***. OED has the adjective ***gravific** - That makes heavy or produces weight*.

Comment: -1 for verbal anarchy.

Comment: +1 for verbal anarchy. By the way, some [actual gravity wells](https://xkcd.com/681/) might as well be entered into the record.

Comment: How about "black hole", if you're being figurative.

Comment: Is there any reason "massive" or "dense" wouldn't work?

Comment: @keshlam The context seems to indicate that the gravity may or may not have to be an effect of mass.  Since I'm often in a Sci-Fi headspace, it's easier for me to bifurcate the two.

Answer (score 50):

Given the laws of physics, *massive* would seem to fit the bill.

Comment: This is undoubtedly *correct* (so +1), however in a non-scientific context it may confuse the reader for whom a "compact massive object" (such as a neutron star) would be nonsensical.

Comment: Confuse them more than "gravacious" ???

Comment: There is nothing wrong with [compact massive object](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22compact+massive+object%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8). Physicists use it.

Comment: Yes, there is. They're unsafe is what's wrong with them. Don't go near them.

Comment: @JohnLawler Bigoted discrimination against any kind of cosmic body has no part to play on an enlightened website for the discussion of English usage. Instead of "unsafe" please use "differently safe" in the future ;)

Comment: @MarvMills I think you just coined the term "massist".

Comment: @ChrisH For a less educated audience, use *heavy*. I have heard physicists use this.

Comment: @Cerberus There is a distinct difference between being *heavy* and being *massive*. *Massive* means to have a lot of mass, whereas *heavy* means to have a lot of weight. Mass and weight may often correlate, but they are certainly not the same.

Comment: @DavidK: Correct, but for a less educated audience, they're the same.

Comment: @DavidK: Of course, hence my "less educated audience".

Comment: @PeterShor that was my point. Physicists use it (hence my example) but it's a term (and by extension so is the use of *massive* in the sense of "being a large mass") that is likely to confuse someone lacking knowledge of physics terminology.

Comment: @logophobe Now you guys are making me want to suggest "mass-hole" as an answer.

Comment: @ChrisH I’m not sure it would be all that confusing. I’m no great shakes at physics (in fact, I’m about three levels below abysmal), but even I know that a _supermassive black hole_, apart from being a song by Muse, are so named not because they’re really, really big, but because they have an enormous mass. In the right context (and if the text makes it clear that physics terminology is more likely to pop up than colloquial lingo), _massive_ should be relatively clear to most people, I’d say.

Comment: I don't think the massive *means* possessing gravity. Otherwise saying that massive objects possess gravity would be definitionally trivial.

Comment: This is arguably the best answer but only in light of a literal correlation. However, the word "massive" invokes an image of a gigantic or gargantuan object (at least to me), in terms of the amount of space it fills. I want a word that catches the nuance and avoids carrying that overtone.

Comment: @WillieWheeler true, "massive" technically means possessing mass, and if one somehow invents a situation in which mass is not correlated to gravity, then an object could be massive without having much gravity, or vice versa. Though I doubt anyone except a physicist would go through that thought process.

Comment: @DavidZ A possible example of the sort of semantic/physical decoupling under discussion might be "artificial gravity" inside a rotating spacecraft. One might apply the OP's desired word (even if only as a manner of speaking) to the craft under higher rates of rotation without there being any corresponding change in mass.

Answer (score 4):

You can consider the adjectives ***hypergravitational*** or ***megagravitational*** to describe a very strong gravitational pull. (they can be hyphenated also)

> Centrifuges were used to create **hyper-gravitational** forces in the last quarter of the 19th century by Tsiolkovskiy, among others, to study levels of acceleration tolerance in various species.
>
> <sub>*Humans in Spaceflight, Book 2* By Carolyn S. Leach Huntoon</sub>

---

> Scientists tell us that Jupiter has been deflecting harmful asteroids from Earth for years. Its **megagravitational** field pulls those asteroids off course and deflects them back into space.
>
> <sub>*Planets and Possibilities: Explore the World of the Zodiac Beyond Just Your Sign* By Susan Miller</sub>

---

Additionally, ***hypergravity*** has a particular meaning:

> Hypergravity is defined as the condition where the force of gravity exceeds that on the surface of the Earth. This is expressed as being greater than 1 g. [[Wikipedia]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergravity)

Comment: It would be better to use *supergravitational* or *magnigravitational*, in order to avoid Graeco-Latin hybrids.

Comment: @Cerberus: I didn't mention *supergravitational* because it has another use. See: [Supergravity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supergravity)

Comment: Ugh, so many terminology!

Comment: @Cerberus Certainly! While one is driving in an autokinetic and feeling claustrotimorous about encroaching [hybrid Latin-Greek words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_word), we should certainly condemn the hyperenergotic imaginations that create such abominations! (Or we can just accept that they're actually pretty normal parts of English... Though, I do like the sound of *supergravitational* quite a lot.)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: Very good! (We already have so many ugly hybrids; let's avoid casting any new ones into this world. I try to avoid them whenever I can, although there are plenty that one cannot avoid, such as sociology, television...you don't know what it's like, being a Greek divinity.)

Answer (score 1):

From [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/weightfulness) :

> **weightfulness**
>
> > The quality or state of being weightful; heaviness; gravity

---

@steveverrill proposition : from [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/weightiness) :

> **weightiness**
>
> > The quality of being weighty

Comment: Oh, c'mon! Anybody hearing the word _weightfulness_ would understand _waitfulness_ (or perhaps _wakefulness_, depending on ambient noise), and would remain innocent of any discussion of _weight_ or mass in the discourse.

Comment: What about context? I just quoting a dictionary, I didn't invented it.

Comment: Wiktionary is not really a dictionary. It's a list. If you want a dictionary, get a real dictionary; what's free on the web is often defective.

Comment: Like stackoverflow and all SE?

Comment: **weightiness** sounds far more common / natural to my British ears

Comment: @steveverrill I'm adding it, but it lose his gravity ref. ^^

Answer (score 1):

As I have used it in Sci-Fi concepts within my own stuff, I have used the phrase:

**Gravitically significant**.

If something does not possess enough gravity (due to mass) to be orbited, then it is not gravitically significant.

Depending on usage, this could be a fuzzy definition.  Some starships (in my stuff) generate enough gravity to disturb star systems, and are gravitically significant.  But, to an astronaut on an asteroid, the astroid is gravitically significant.  The asteroid to the star system, is not.

As a single term, **gravitic** is about as close as I can get.  "It exerts gravity."   (yes, everything does, but so much of that is unnoticed, so is it, on a practical sense?)

Answer (score 0):

It's rather clunky, but I've occasionally heard **strongly gravitating** for this. Though apparently "gravitate" also has a [different meaning](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gravitate), arguably more common, which might lead to people getting confused.

> 1:  to move under the influence of gravitation
>
> 2 a:  to move toward something
>
> 2 b:  to be drawn or attracted especially by natural inclination

Answer (score -1):

The word *gravity* itself is a noun form of *grave,* in the same way that *seriousness* is a noun form of *serious*. We have phrases such as "the *gravity* of the situation" because of this.

For this reason, I say the word for "possessing a large gravity well" is *grave.*

Comment: That's not what 'grave' means.

Comment: Bullshit. 'grave' means "giving cause for alarm; serious,"  while 'gravity' means "seriousness or solemnity of manner," and both derive from 'gravis' in Latin. You can shove that downvote right up your ass.

Comment: The question isn't about gravity in the sense of 'seriousness or solemnity of manner', it's about the physical force. Derivation is a very unreliable guide to current meanings.

Comment: When Newton called it 'gravity' it only had the 'seriousness' meaning. He obviously thought the meaning was close enough, otherwise he would've picked a different word.

Answer (score -2):

***gravity hole***

Expected, and well established:

> [Everything:](https://books.google.ca/books?id=aBSQAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA164&dq=%22gravity%20hole%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=2bg3VeWhNYrjsATA-YDYDg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22gravity%20hole%22&f=false) - Page 164 L0g0s - 2014
>
> Vokk then stepped back inside truth, losing all the particles of
>   complex matter that had attached to his energy of reason as he passed
>   through the anti-Higgs particles around the **gravity hole** I had
>   created.